# Android studio 1.2 Java 7 Could not create window texture

Tags: java, android

I work with linux mint 17. 
I downloaded java 7 using: sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk icedtea-7-plugin

Then I installed Android studio from 
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.2.0.12/android-studio-ide-141.1890965-linux.zip

unpacked it, created a helloworld application for api22:Android 5.1 
When I try to test it using
tools/android/Avd Manager
I have there a device: Nexus 5 api 22x86, resolution 1080x1920 api 22

I get this error when I try to start the hello world program on the device:
/home/en/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_22_x86
ERROR: Could not create window texture: Texture dimensions are limited to 2048x2048

I get the same error error message for sample programs using File/Import Sample

Thanks in advance for helpful hints.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your GPU or drivers...try toggling the Use Host GPU setting for the device.

Comment: In studio tools/Android/AVD manager, select write, the only point I found fits: Use Host GPU, I unchecked this, but the error remains the same.<br> if there is something else I can try, please describe in detail, what to do.

Comment: That's the option I was talking about. Other thing to try would be to try a different AVD, one with a smaller screen.

Comment: I added a Galaxy Nexus API 22 virtual machine, 720x1280 screen, it works. Thank you,

Comment: However, my app is not uploaded, and I was not able to upload it onto this device.

Comment: **Question*: find A* -name *.apk -print      
*Answer*: Android/Sdk/tools/apps/SdkController/bin/SdkControllerApp.apk  This is what I get if I search .apk files. My projects are in AndroidStudioProjects, there is not a single .apk file in that directory.  I have nothing to upload into my device.

Comment: I found the solution: start Run/Run app. This loads the device and uploads the application. Thanks again for your help.